# How to check if webservice is up, using Qt

Tags: c++, web-services, qt, http, networking

I wrote some code to monitor a SOAP webservice. Basically it uses QNetworkAccessManager to send an HTTP GET request to the webservice address, and if receives a response then I know the service is up. I thought this was working, but every once in a while ( once every couple of days) I'll get a notification saying the server is down, and then next time it checks it says it's up again. So the server isn't actually going down, something is happening to the request. I was wondering if there is a better way to monitor a webservice, below is some pseudo code to show you what I did:

```
main{
    Qtimer timer;
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(send()));
    timer.start(300000);
}

send(){
    QNetworkAccessManager *qnam;
    connect(qnam, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(requestFinished(QNetworkReply*));
    qnam.get("https://testWebservice.com/TEST/webservice");
}

requestFinished(QNetworkReply *reply){
    QByteArray data = reply.getData();
    if(reply.error == some sort of error indicating server is down, or if reply == empty){
        ***SERVER DOWN***
    }
    else{
        ***SERVER UP***
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
changed the *if* condition to include error checking

Answer (score 0):

Checking whether the network reply content is empty to make sure that webservice is down does not seem to me to be a good solution in general case.

I would suggest to use `QNetworkReply::error()` method to check whether error occurs.
see http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qnetworkreply.html#error for details.

**UPDATE**
It is not mentioned how reply data is get from `QNetworkReply` object. I presume that something like `QIODevice::readAll/read()` is used. If so then empty data reply does not mean that error occured on server side. See e.g. http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qiodevice.html#readAll

When there is no network error but reply data is unexpectedly empty then I'd assume that webservice is up but something goes wrong with request processing on webservice side or with request/responce transfer.

Comment: that if statement is general..i.e. it could just as easily be if(no error) etc...

Comment: What exact error status are you getting when your code reports error?